# How to solve this differential equation: $Ay''+ B(y')^2 + c = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have already tried it solving after taking $u = y'$ but still I am getting $Au' + Bu^2 + C$. How to solve this new equation.

Also, this is not a Bernoulli equation as the 3rd term doesn't have any $y$ term.

Any suggestions, please.

When I put this equation in Wolfram Alpha, it says "Try again with additional computation time" for which a premium account is needed, which I don't have.

I need to work it out completely, just knowing the answer is also not enough in my case.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Separate variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: 
$$Au' + Bu^2 + C=0$$

Assuming $A\neq 0$:
$$u'=-\frac{B}{A}u^2-\frac{C}{A}$$
$$\dfrac{du}{-\frac{B}{A}u^2-\frac{C}{A}}=dx$$

Essentially this boils down to integrating the left hand side for different combinations of $B$ and $C$.

For example: If $B,C>0$

$$-\frac{A}{\sqrt{BC}}\arctan \left(\sqrt{\frac{B}{C}}u\right) =x+c$$

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $u=\exp(\frac{B}{A}y)$. Then
$$
u''=\frac{B}{A^2}u(Ay''+By'^2)=-\frac{BC}{A^2}u
$$
This has the usual trigonometric solutions, $u=R\cos(\omega x+\phi)$, $ω=\frac{\sqrt{BC}}{A}$, so that
$$
y=\frac{A}{B}\ln(R\cos(\omega x+\phi)).
$$

Answer (score -1):

ok lets go : let u=y' then u'=y''

Au'+Bu<sup>2</sup>+C=0

$\dfrac{du}{-\frac{B}{A}u^2-\frac{C}{A}}=dx$

$-\frac{A}{\sqrt{BC}}\arctan \left(\sqrt{\frac{B}{C}}u\right) =x$+c<sub>1</sub>

${\sqrt{\frac{B}{C}}}u=- tan({\frac{\sqrt{BC}}{A}}(x+$c<sub>1</sub>))

$u=-{\sqrt{\frac{C}{B}}} tan({\frac{\sqrt{BC}}{A}}(x+$c<sub>1</sub>)) ,   u=y'

$\int dy=-\int {\sqrt{\frac{C}{B}}} tan({\frac{\sqrt{BC}}{A}}(x+$c<sub>1</sub>)) dx

$y=\frac{A}{B} ln(cos({\frac{\sqrt{BC}}{A}}(x+$c<sub>1</sub>))) + c<sub>2</sub>

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).